# If $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ then is $f \circ f$ Riemann integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, riemann-integration

I know the composition of Riemann integrable functions is not necessarily Riemann integrable. But I am not finding any argument how to conclude this for self composition, or how to find a counterexample. $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ means that the discontinuity set of $f$ is of measure zero. But the discontinuity of the composition is a larger set, so we cannot conclude anything.

Similarly for the self composition of measurable functions: is it measurable or not? I am unable to find a counterexample.

Comment: Your second paragraph is a very different question and should be asked in a separate post (though it may also have an answer on this site already).  You should also clarify what you mean by "measurable": Borel measurable? Lebesgue measurable? On what domain?

Comment: If you know two Riemann integrable functions $g,h$ whose composition $h \circ g$ is not Riemann integrable, try creating a piecewise function of horizontally and vertically shifted versions of it, so that $f \circ f$ looks like $h \circ h$ up to shifts.

Comment: Domain is same [a,b] and Lebesgue measureable

Comment: I mean $h \circ g$ in previous comment.

Comment: For Riemann Integrable answer is no I guess, I understand just not able to find the precise counterexample.

Comment: Your question was about $f \circ f$ (composition of a function with itself) but you edited the title to $f \circ g$.  I changed it back so that they match.  If you have a separate question about $f \circ g$ then please write a new post.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose you have Riemann integrable functions $g,h : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ such that $h \circ g$ is not Riemann integrable.  Define $f : [0,3] \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} g(x) + 2, & 0 \le x \le 1 \\ 123.456 & 1 < x < 2 \\ h(x-2), & 2 \le x \le 3. \end{cases}$$
Then $f \circ f = h \circ g$ on $[0,1]$.  I leave it to you to verify that $f$ is again Riemann integrable, that $f \circ f$ is not, and to make adjustments if you don't like the domain and range I chose.

Comment: For me, this is a great answer (+2).